# How to stop the keyboard to open in a modal in calendar input

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html

What is the missing part in a html that would make the calendar window in phones to open like this http://prntscr.com/dbjc19 instead of like this http://prntscr.com/dbjcub ?

Comment: Make sure that the field should be a button, not textField that takes input from keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

JS blur method un focus to textbox and keyboard not open :)

```js
$('#notFocusableInput').on('touchend mouseup', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).blur();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="notFocusableInput" type="text">
  </body>

</html>
```